# how to generate tag cloud with acts_as_taggable_on_steroids

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the tag functionality working ok but can't generate a tag_cloud

### in my controller:

```
def tag_cloud
  @tags = Article.tag_counts # returns all the tags used 
end
```

### in the view:

```
<% tag_cloud Article.tag_counts.sort { |x, y| x.name <=> y.name }, %w(x-small small normal large x-large) do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_url( :tag => tag.name ), :class => css_class %>
<% end %>
```

I always get a undefined method error for `tag_cloud`

Answer (score 0):

You can't call controller methods from the view.  Try putting it in a model or passing it to the view from the controller.

If this isn't helpful enough, try editing the question and including more details such as the full definition of `tag_cloud`, explain why you're setting @tag but not using it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't look like it'll do all you want, but to remedy the undefined method error, the proper place for auxiliary methods for views is in the helper, so move the method `tag_cloud` there instead.

You'll find it in `app/helpers/controllername_helper.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

`tag_cloud` defined in module `TagsHelper`. You need to include it in corresponding helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include TagsHelper
end
```

Also there is no need in controllers `tag_cloud`

Answer (score 0):

sergeykish.com is correct, you just need to include the helper in /app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include TagsHelper
end
```